# How to include special characters in regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have the pattern like this:

```
(example:gift_card_$250,11)(example:gift_card_250,22)
```

I want to translate it to

```
col1            col2
gift_card_$250  11
gift_card_250   22
```

I tried this:

```
\((example:\w+),(\d+)\)
```

but it misses the first entry because of the `$` sign. How could I include special characters (basically everything but `,`)?

Comment: Use `[^,]+` to match 1+ of non-comma characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a character group:

```
\((example:[\w$]+),(\d+)\)
```

Include any other special characters you want to match in the group.

See a [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/FEZN6Q/1) demo.